# How to override mocked response of $httpBackend in Angular?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, mocking

Is is possible to override or re-define mocked response in mocked $httpBackend?

I have test like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

  //Fake Backend
  $httpBackend.when('GET', '/myUrl').respond({}); //Empty data from server
  ...some more fake url responses...     
 }
```

This is fine for most cases but I have few tests where I need to return something different for the same URL. But it seems that once the when().respond() is defined I can not change it afterwards in code like this:

Different response in a single specific test:

```
it('should work', inject(function($controller){
  $httpBackend.when('GET', '/myUrl').respond({'some':'very different value with long text'})

  //Create controller

  //Call the url

  //expect that {'some':'very different value with long text'} is returned
  //but instead I get the response defined in beforeEach
}));
```

How do I do that?
My code is now untestable :(

Comment: I have somewhat "solved" it by splitting the unit test into 2 files. Each file has it own $httpBackend.when().respond() definitions. It is ugly solution, but so far I did not find anything better.

Comment: I encountered the same issue when using ng-describe mocks of http as in example https://github.com/kensho/ng-describe#mock-httpget - it seems under the hood it uses `$httpBackend.when(...)` and when I later want to `deps.$httpBackend.expect("POST", "foobar")` and assert with `deps.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();` I get an error `Error: Unsatisfied requests: POST foobar`. It seems using ng-describe `$http` mock makes it impossible to use `httpBackend.expect()` later.

Answer (score 28):

The docs seem to suggest this style:

```
var myGet;
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = $_httpBackend_;
    myGet = $httpBackend.whenGET('/myUrl');
    myGet.respond({});
});
```

...

```
it('should work', function() {
    myGet.respond({foo: 'bar'});
    $httpBackend.flush();
    //now your response to '/myUrl' is {foo: 'bar'}
});
```

Comment: [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#when): "when() returns an object with respond method that controls how a matched request is handled. You can save this object for later use and invoke respond again in order to change how a matched request is handled."

Comment: What if I have the reference (`myGet`) in some 'base class' file that shares `beforEach` for all tests and I need to reference it in some other particular test/file?

Answer (score 12):

Use a function in the respond, for example:

```
var myUrlResult = {};

beforeEach(function() {
  $httpBackend.when('GET', '/myUrl').respond(function() {
    return [200, myUrlResult, {}];
  });
});

// Your test code here.

describe('another test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    myUrlResult = {'some':'very different value'};
  });

  // A different test here.

});
```

Answer (score 9):

One other option is:

You can use 
`$httpBackend.expect().respond()` instead of `$httpBackend.when().respond()`

Using `expect()`, you can push the same url twice and get different responses in the same order you pushed them.

Comment: actually, `when()` is supposed to be used for E2E testing instead of unit testing.

Answer (score 6):

In your test use .expect() instead of .when()

```
var myUrlResult = {};

beforeEach(function() {
  $httpBackend.when('GET', '/myUrl')
      .respond([200, myUrlResult, {}]);
});


it("overrides the GET" function() {
  $httpBackend.expect("GET", '/myUrl')
      .respond([something else]);
  // Your test code here.
});
```

Comment: What goes in `[something else]`? Is the `.respond` in the test needed?

Answer (score 0):

You could reset 'when' responses in the same function where you conduct the tests.

```
it('should work', inject(function($controller){
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/myUrl').respond({'some':'value'})
    // create the controller
    // call the url
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(data.some).toEqual('value');
});
it('should also work', inject(function($controller){
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/myUrl').respond({'some':'very different value'})
    // create the controller
    // call the url
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(data.some).toEqual('very different value');
});
```

See an example in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7oFQvQLIQFGAG1AEU1MU?p=preview

Comment: You plunkr doesn't set the response in the beforeEach method, so you're not actually overriding any value.  You add a beforeEach and everything starts failing: http://plnkr.co/edit/A44vSX?p=preview